# How to keep "Force update of Snapshots/Releases" option in Update maven project option checked everytime I update maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, m2e

Whenever I want to update my maven project, I need to check the ***Force update of Snapshots/Releases*** option everytime which I find very irritating.

[Update maven project window Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXpHI.png)

Can there be any setting which can pre-check this option whenever I press Alt-f5 to open the ***Update maven project*** window.

Comment: Not sure that eclipse has that as configurable .One command that i know which may or may not help is "mvn clean install -U"

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav. But I am aware of this command.